# Python algorithm to sequentially generate all possible outcomes of slot machine

Tags: python, algorithm

I have 3 lists like this:

```
reel1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

reel2 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

reel3 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

I need a generator function that can sequentially give me these:

First output:

```
[
    [1,2,3]
    [1,2,3]
    [1,2,3]
]
```

Second output:

```
[
    [1,2,3]
    [1,2,3]
    [2,3,4] # Sequentially go through the list
]
```

...

9th output:

```
[
    [1,2,3]
    [2,3,4] # Next block of 3 of the second list
    [1,2,3] 
]
```

All the way to:

```
[
    [8,9,10] # Last block of 3 of the first list
    [8,9,10] # Last block of 3 of the second list
    [8,9,10] # Last block of 3 of the third list
]
```

What is an effective algorithm to achieve the above?

My current method: I'm using 3 *for* loops to sequentially go through all 3 lists, but I don't think it's effective. Also, if I have more than 3 lists, I will have to indent a lot.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
>>> from itertools import product
>>> reel = list(range(1, 11))
>>> for i in product(zip(reel, reel[1:], reel[2:]), repeat=3):
...     print(i)
```

To handle the wraparound mentioned in the comments, you can use

```
>>> for i in product(zip(*(reel[j:]+reel[:j] for j in range(3))), repeat=3):
...     print(i)
```

Comment: I think this is missing the wrap-around cases `(9, 10, 1)` and `(10, 1, 2)` (although that wasn't asked for in the question)

Comment: The OP doesn't seem to want that.

Comment: Agreed it's not asked for explicitly, but OP stated that it's a slot machine with reels, it seems reasonable to conclude

Comment: `reel = range(1,11) + range(1,3)` would handle the wrap around cases if desired

Comment: Thanks @gnibbler. Thanks @PeterGibson. Actually I wanted a wrap-around too. I'm on Python 3, so `+` doesn't work with `range()`.

Comment: @Lavaboom, You can use `list(range())` or type them all out like you did in the question

Comment: @Lavaboom You can a) use `list(range(..)) + list(range(..))` or b) use `list(itertools.chain(range(...), range(...)))`

Answer (score 1):

```
for i in itertools.product([[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10][i:i+3] for i in range(0,8)], repeat=3):
    print(i)
```